# How to search for people in Google Plus using email?

Tags: google-api, google-plus

How to search for people in Google Plus using email?

e.g. this query never returns anything:

https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people?query=[email_address]@gmail.com&key=MY_KEY

I tried a db of a thousand emails at least,

Also I have an account with very strange name, when I search by name I get the result, but with email I don't , I tried to url encode the email but still it didn't work.

Comment: it's as @BrettJ mentioned, only possible when people enable this, and almost nobody enabled this

Comment: can you show me on this profile: plus.google.com/105807203095810748680 ?  mail is public

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The email address must be set as a public field in the user's Google+ profile to be able to search and find that entry. The [people.search](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/search) method only searches public fields.

Comment: can you show me on this profile: https://plus.google.com/105807203095810748680 ? mail is public

Comment: From what I can see, searching by email does not work. I also tested it on my own profile, and the email is public.

Comment: The behavior might have changed since 2013. Its been quite a while since I've tried.